# PyMad IOError (when I open file with not latin characters)

Tags: python, ioerror

I use PyMad/PyAudio for play mp3 files.

When I open a file with non-latin characters Python raises the following error:

```
IOError: Object must have a read method
```

on the line:

```
self.mf = mad.MadFile(filename)
```

Usually this happens if the filename contains non-Latin characters.